# Does a shared excel have any limitations when used with Java + Apache POI?

Tags: excel, file-upload, apache-poi, pivot-table, cell

The question is very simple but I've never seen it asked on stack. Will Apache POI work with a shared excel (meaning the excel is "co-authored" with other accounts as per Excel verbiage)? Will I still be able to create a pivot table using Java? How about upload a file to a certain cell?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "Excel verbiage"?

Comment: @SolarMike https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-happened-to-shared-workbooks-150fc205-990a-4763-82f1-6c259303fe05

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm facing a similar issue. Shared Excel file, user makes changes, doesn't save, Java makes changes, saves, user saves and the result is that the Java changes are deleted (overwritten). Doesn't seem like Apacha POI has any support for this.